# Error when trying to use a CollectionViewController without a ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, swift2

I have been all day trying to use a CollectionViewController instead of a ViewController. In my storyboard I have a CollectionViewController,  collection view inside, and a button inside the cell.
My code is:
On CollectionViewController:

```
override func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return numberOfButtons
}
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCollectionViewCell

    cell.buttonInCell.selected = buttonsStatusList[indexPath.row]
    cell.setContents(indexPath.row)
    cell.updateButtonAppearance()

    return cell
}
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let tappedCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCollectionViewCell
    tappedCell.buttonInCell.selected = !tappedCell.buttonInCell.selected
    buttonsStatusList[indexPath.row] = tappedCell.buttonInCell.selected
    tappedCell.updateButtonAppearance()
}
```

In CustomCollectionViewCell I have:

```
@IBOutlet weak var buttonInCell: UIButton!

let buttonBorderWidth: CGFloat = 1.0
var buttonRadius: CGFloat!

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    buttonRadius = frame.height / 2
}

func setContents(row: Int) {
    buttonInCell.setTitle(String(row + 1), forState: .Normal)
    buttonInCell.setTitleColor(UIColor.blueColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    buttonInCell.layer.cornerRadius = buttonRadius
    buttonInCell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor
    buttonInCell.layer.borderWidth = buttonBorderWidth
}

func updateButtonAppearance() {
    if buttonInCell.selected {
        buttonInCell.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: .Normal)
        buttonInCell.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor
    } else {
        buttonInCell.setTitleColor(UIColor.blueColor(), forState: .Normal)
        buttonInCell.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
    }
}
```

I guess the problem is in the connections of the Storyboard but I'm not able to find it.
The error I get is:
`Could not cast value of type 'UICollectionViewCell' (0x10c7b6408) to 'UICollectionViewController.CustomCollectionViewCell' (0x10aee8470).`
In `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier`

Comment: Did you set the class name of the cell in the storyboard?

Comment: Yes, @YiminLin, actually, also I've tried to delete everything about the CustomCell and using just a UICollectionViewCell but I get an empty white screen without cells(I set the cell's background to blue in storyboard)

Comment: Yes, @AaoIi. The problem is solved! I still don't know why `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` doesn't work, so I can deselect buttons, but you made your part. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You didn't change too much. I 'm very new in programming, so I put the functions in places where they probably shouldn't be.

Comment: Welcome its my pleasure, i will try to solve that also !

Comment: @Danowsky , I've updated my answer if you want to deselect the item .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well There was lots of issues which was causing this to happen especially by defining your stuff in `CustomCell`.

- I've redefined the cell class in `cellForItemAtIndexPath` .
- Handle button in each cell clicked by addTarget to method `updateButtonAppearance()` :

  `cell.buttonInCell.addTarget(self, action: "updateButtonAppearance:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)`
- keep track of the selected items with `buttonStatusList` boolean array inside `cellForItemAtIndexPath`.

**Update:** To Deselect the item and back the color to default replace the if statement in `updateButtonAppearance` with :

```
if cell.buttonInCell.backgroundColor == UIColor.blueColor() {
    cell.buttonInCell.setTitleColor(UIColor.blueColor(), forState: .Normal)
    cell.buttonInCell.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
    buttonsStatusList[sender.tag] = false
} else {
    cell.buttonInCell.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: .Normal)
    cell.buttonInCell.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor
    buttonsStatusList[sender.tag] = true

}
```

Note : You don't need to use `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` method anymore !